# Connecting two 3V batteries in series on a PCB, but the total is only 3V. What could be wrong? , Suggestions for Reverse mount LEDs

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, led, current, pcb-design

[image]

I've made a PCB based on the given circuit, but after connecting two 3V batteries, the overall voltage difference becomes 3V. It is expected to be 5.5 to 6V. What could be wrong?

I'm working on the 10mm x 8 mm board.

Here are the LED specs
RED LED - mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528SURCKT09-1602052.pdf
Green LED - mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528ZGCKT09-1602097.pdf Yellow LED - mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528SYCKT09-1602219.pdf
Blue LED - mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528QBS_D09-1602151.pdf

Please suggest any right battery source to power up the LEDs with max brightness , as these are reverse mount LEDs. Light needs to penetrate the PCB.

Comment: What batteries they are, and did you only measure voltage under load so LEDs were on, or did you measure open circuit voltage without load? Do you have an estimate how much current draw is?

Comment: They are 3v coin cell batteries.  

open circuit voltage without load - Means measuring the voltage of the batteries directly? If yes, but doing it the voltage was above 5 volts.

Comment: If you need the light to penetrate a PCB, then make a hole to the PCB.

Comment: I expect that smudged effect on the other side. So cannot put a hole

Comment: There's plastic components that are intended to diffuse light.

Comment: The idea is to make one like these - https://hackaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ReverseMountedLEDs.jpg?w=800

Answer (score 4):

If these are 3V lithium coin cells, you are badly overloading them, so the voltage will drop.

Here is a typical datasheet:

[image]

https://www.duracell.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/CR2032JCS0820.pdf

Note the 0.3mA typical and 3 mA maximum current.  It looks like you were aiming for a load of more than 100 mA, which is not possible so the voltage drops.

If you want 100 mA at > 3V, a small lithium ion battery would make sense. It would be rechargable, although you don't actually have to recharge it if this is a single use device. You could also use a 9v cell would also work, although it would be larger.

Comment: But as per spec an LED requires 20mA. If the discharge current is only 0.3mA How come a single coin cell powers up an LED. I don't understand the math here. Please throw some light on this

Comment: @m4ng0: 20 mA isn't the minimum current for the LED. Most modern LEDs will operate just fine on much lower currents.

Comment: @m4ng0 The minimum current for an LED to light up is very low, often you can see them glow with nanoamps of current, so the few milliamps that battery can supply is easily enough to light an LED, although much dimmer than it would be at 20 mA (max brightness).

Comment: Please suggest a right power source for this circuit which could yield max brightness.

Comment: I'm working on the 10mm x 8 mm board. Here's the LED specs

RED LED - https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528SURCKT09-1602052.pdf

Green LED - https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528ZGCKT09-1602097.pdf

Yellow LED - https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528SYCKT09-1602219.pdf

Blue LED - https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/216/AA3528QBS_D09-1602151.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Use four AA alkaline battery cells in series making about 6V when new.
Four AAA alkaline cells will last for about 1/3 the time of AA cells.
The brightness of the LEDs will slowly drop as the batteries become discharged.

Comment: In that case 3 aaa batteries are sufficient ? Cuz I have a space constraint .

Comment: It is obvious that you need a fairly large battery to provide enough current for the LEDs to be bright enough that will last longer than a few seconds.